# What are the chances to get a female starter, and is there anyway to increase the chances?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm playing Pokemon X currently, and I really want a female Fennekin (as seen in the trailers). I've read the chances of getting a female starter are low, but not impossible.

[Someone on GF](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67448241) said that the gender of your starter depends on the gender you pick (at the start of the game). Is this a rumor or is there any correlation?

So, will I just have to keep soft resetting my game or what can I do to increase the odds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The gender ratio for the 6th generation starters is currently unknown, but [all starters so far had a ratio of 12.5% female / 87.5% male, or 1 : 7](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_gender_ratio#1_.E2.99.80_:_7_.E2.99.82).

The gender of your Pokémon does **not** depend on your character's gender. Both male and female protagonists can have either male or female starters.

> This specific gender ratio is used to make it more difficult in breeding more of them since players usually get them as gifts or Fossils rather than catch them in the wild. ***All starter and Fossil Pokémon are in this group***.

The only way to ensure you'll get a female starter is indeed by saving the game beforehand and reloading it as necessary.