# How do you know what gender your Fennekin is?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So, I am very new to the game, and I really want a female Fennekin, although how do I know the gender? I know for the pickachu it's the tail shape, but no idea about the fennekin. Help?

Comment: You can also check out this question on how to get a female starter: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135903/what-are-the-chances-to-get-a-female-starter-and-is-there-anyway-to-increase-th

Comment: Simple: "[*Men are from Mars* (♂), *women are from Venus* (♀).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_symbol)"

Answer (score 11):

The gender of a Pokemon is displayed in a variety of places throughout the game. The two you'll see most commonly are right next to a Pokemon's name in a battle, or on the Pokemon status screen in the menu.

This picture gives an example of the battle screen:

[image: Upper battle screen in Pokemon X/Y]

And this picture gives an example of the Pokemon status screen:

[image: Pokemon status screen in Pokemon X/Y]

Males have a ♂, while females have a ♀ instead.

---

Fennekin, like all starter Pokemon, is only generated as female one out of every eight times on average, so it may take some time to find a female one.

Comment: Further explanation, it is about the red (first and second picture) and red (seconds picture) icon. Thingy pointing up, means male. Thingy pointing down, means female. Chespin is male, Fletchling female.